# How to register .net dll as COM correctly?

Tags: .net

I have registered my dll as COM via below command via admin access.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe /codebase dllPath
it showed Types registered successfully.
i could seen the registered info on registry

It was not work when i try to invoke the function.

```
Type t= Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progid);
dynamic o =Activator.CreateInstance(t);
string result=o.GetResult();
```

The exception is like below and trace the t is null.
Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: type

Platform target: x64 and Any CPU both are failed.
Marked make assembly COM visible.

Comment: Forgetting to use the [ProgId attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.progidattribute?view=netcore-3.1), typically.  Do keep in mind that you are *not*  testing anything by doing this with C# code.  Well, other than the missing [ProgId] perhaps.

Comment: Hi Hans,it's working well when i ticked the register for COM interop but we need to deploy it on server which just installed the framework.